# Adding value from other table to value of the current table in h2

Tags: sql, database, h2

I have a table `medicine`, and another table `cart`. Both have a field name `quantity` and `id`.
I want to add `cart.quantity` to `medicine.quantity` if their `id` are equal

Since I am converting the code from MySQL to h2, I tried the MySQL compatibility mode using MODE=MySQL, but following code doesn't work

```
update medicine, cart 
set medicine.quantity = medicine.quantity+cart.quantity 
where medicine.id = cart.id;
```

I tried using select statement as given in official documentation

```
update medicine med1 
set med1.quantity = med1.quantity+
                   (select cart.quantity from cart where cart.id = med1.id)
```

I expected the output to be sum of quantity when the ids match
But I am getting NULL value in `medicine.quantity` for all rows after performing the update operation.

What can be changed so that `medicine.quantity` will stay the same when there are no id match, or added with `cart.quantity` when id match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using where exists

```
set quantity = quantity +
                (select quantity from cart where id = med1.id) 
where exists (select quantity from cart where id = med1.id)"
```

Answer (score 0):

That update statement is updating all records in the table. So the `med1.quantity` field will update to NULL is there are no records for the ID in the cart table.

You should add a `WHERE` clause after so:

```
update medicine med1 
set med1.quantity = med1.quantity+
(select cart.quantity from cart where cart.id = med1.id)
where med1.id in (Select cart.id from cart)
```